# Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 64 (or the query data is unbuffered)

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with php and mysql and suddenly I get

> mysql_data_seek() [function.mysql-data-seek]: Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 64 (or the query data is unbuffered)

What does this mean.

I have no idea where to start to debug this one.

---

**This class is passed a mysql resource into it's constructor**

```
class dbResult {

    private $result;
    private $num_rows;

    function __construct($result) {
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    function result($type = 'object') {
        @mysql_data_seek($this->result, 0);
        if ($type == 'array')
            return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result);
        if ($type == 'object') {
            if ($this->num_rows() == 1) {
                $data = new stdClass();
                foreach (mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result) as $k => $v)
                    $data->$k = $v;
                return $data;
            }
            if ($this->num_rows() > 1) {
                $data = array();
                while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result)) {
                    $row = new stdClass();
                    foreach ($result as $k => $v)
                        $row->$k = $v;
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    function num_rows() {
        return mysql_num_rows($this->result);
    }

    function num_fields() {
        return mysql_num_fields($this->result);
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry, Had added code but hit the backspace button outside of the textbox, added code again.

Comment: Before calling mysql_data_seek always check mysql_num_rows(result) >=1. May be the result set is empty

Comment: you can't start with zero: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

QOUTE : "a seek to 0 will fail with a E_WARNING and mysql_data_seek() will return FALSE"

Comment: Remove the @ before `mysql_data_seek`, call `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of your script - and if needed also add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Now you'll see the errors being dumped to the screen (or alternatively you could also log them of course). My guess is that you're passing an empty result set to a dbResult->result() call.

Comment: Cheers guys, Was infact an empty data set, Have now implemented error handing.

@Shakti Singh care to post your comment as a details answer?

Comment: @Hailwood, Glad and posted as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if the result set is empty  `mysql_data_seek()` will fail with a `E_WARNING`. That is I think happening in you case because you are not checking whether the result set is empty or not before calling the `mysql_data_seek()`.

Always check the result for number of rows if they are >=1 then you are safe to call `mysql_data_seek()`