# Warning: mysql_data_seek(): Offset 1 is invalid for MySQL result index 5 (or the query data is unbuffered)

Tags: php

Please can anyone assist. I am trying to execute the following php code:

```
   $sql="SELECT * FROM vendors WHERE vuid=".$uid."AND status="."'c'";
   $sql=$sql . "LIMIT 0, 10"; 
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
   $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);        

   for($i=0;$i<$numrows;$i++)
   {

    if($numrows>0) 
    {
    mysql_data_seek($result,$i);
}
```

I am receiving the following error Warning: mysql_data_seek(): Offset 1 is invalid for MySQL result index 5 (or the query data is unbuffered). $numrows is 2, therefore the range of the mysql_data_seek is valid.

Thanking in advance

Comment: could you try running the code you have shown us(after closing the braces of course). I think the code you stripped out is the cause.

Answer (score 4):

if the result set is empty [mysql_data_seek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) will fail with a E_WARNING. That is I think happening in you case because you are not checking whether the result set is empty or not before calling the mysql_data_seek().

Always check the result for number of rows if they are >=1 then you are safe to call mysql_data_seek()

```
if ( mysql_num_rows ( $sql ) > 0 )
{
    // do stuff, you have some results
}
else
{
    // no results to process
}
```

Comment: **Exact** copy paste of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860152/offset-0-is-invalid-for-mysql-result-index-64-or-the-query-data-is-unbuffered), posted Feb 1 '11 at 10:05. Even with the small i in If : _if the result set is empty  mysql_data_seek() will fail with a E_WARNING. That is I think happening in you case because you are not checking whether the result set is empty or not before calling the mysql_data_seek(). Always check the result for number of rows if they are >=1 then you are safe to call mysql_data_seek()_ :)

Comment: I like this answer more because it gives an example. Thank you Moyed. But yes, credit to the source should have been given ;-)